# Get type from interface and remove array

Tags: javascript, typescript

We have an interface defined this way:

```
interface IInitialInterface {
   stack: string,
   overflow: {
      a: string,
      b: string
   }[],
}
```

How can I create a type with only the overflow property removing the array? If I do:

```
type TypeSearched = IInitialInterface['overflow']
```

Then I get:

```
type TypeSearched = {
    a: string,
    b: string
}[]
```

But I want to remove the array.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the member type of an array you can drill in with `ArrayType[number]`. This returns the type that would be returned if you accessed that array with any number.

```
type TypeSearched = IInitialInterface['overflow'][number]
// { a: string; b: string; }
```

---

However, a cleaner approach would be to build the pieces from named little  pieces, rather than disassembling the big piece.

```
interface TypeSearched {
   a: string,
   b: string
}

interface IInitialInterface {
   stack: string,
   overflow: TypeSearched[]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. I was asking for the first method but I think the second one is much cleaner code. Very instructive. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

overflow property is not "typed" in this case, you can do this

```
interface IInitialInterface {
   stack: string,
   overflow: IOverflow[],
}

interface IOverflow {
   a: string,
   b: string
}
```

Then, you can refer to IOverflow of directly instead of through IInitialInterface

```
type TypeSearched: IOverflow;
```